# How to change the order in new commands

Tags: macros

Being quite an amateur to LaTeX, I am sorry, I don't know how to ask my question without telling the whole story:

In a large document, I made a rather simple command for citing (Classical Latin) authors following other conventions than I use for citing modern authors (where I use BibTeX, etc.). This is the command I use:

```
\newcommand{\citeCL}[3]{#1, \emph{#2}, \textbf{#3}}
%\citeCL{author}{text}{chapter}
```

As the first two arguments I use yet other commands from a list of author names and text titles (as I use every name several times and may be inconsistent if writing it in full every time), e.g.,

```
\newcommand{\Per}{N. Per.}
\newcommand{\PerRud}{Rud. gram.}
```

Within the document, I could call the cite command thus:

```
\citeCL{\Per}{\PerRud}{1117}
```

This cite command I use both in footnotes and in this quotation environment:

```
\newcommand{\QuoteCL}[4]{
\vspace{5pt}
\begin{quote}\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt\begin{spacing}{1}
#4 \par\hspace*{\fill}\footnotesize{\citeCL{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\end{spacing}
\end{quote}
\vspace{-20pt}
}
```

In the document I call the command with the same three arguments as for the `\citeCL`, and additionally the text to quote, e.g.,

```
\QuoteCL{\Per}{\PerRud}{§ 1119}{Quis maxime proponendus est quem studeant adolescentes imitari? Marcus Cicero.}
```

All this works fine, and I have used it throughout my thesis. Now I wish to differ between the ways the author names and titles are written in footnotes and in quotations, using the abbreviated form in footnotes and a new, long form in quotations. My intuitive, naive approach was this:

```
\newcommand{\citeCL}[3]{#1, \emph{#2}, \textbf{#3}}
% Original command now used for footnotes

\newcommand{\citeCLLong}[3]{#1Long, \emph{#2Long}, \textbf{#3}}
% New command to be called by the \quoteCL command.

\newcommand{\Per}{N. Per.}
\newcommand{\PerLong}{Niccolò Perotti}
\newcommand{\PerRud}{Rud. gram.}
\newcommand{\PerRudLong}{Rudimenta grammatices}
% Duplicating the list of names and titles, adding a long version to be called by the \citeCLLong:

\newcommand{\QuoteCL}[4]{
\vspace{5pt}
\begin{quote}\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt\begin{spacing}{1}
#4 \par\hspace*{\fill}\footnotesize{\citeCLLong{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\end{spacing}
\end{quote}
\vspace{-20pt}
}
% The command is changed to call the new \citeCLLong

\begin{document}
\QuoteCL{\Per}{\PerRud}{§ 1119}{Quis maxime proponendus est quem studeant adolescentes imitari? Marcus Cicero.}
\end{document}
```

Now to my question: I was hoping that adding `Long` to the arguments in `\citeCLLong` (`#1Long, \emph{#2Long}`) would make LaTeX choose, e.g., `\PerLong` instead of merely `\Per` from my author list, even though I call the `\quoteCL` command with the argument `\Per`. That the `Long` part would be added before it is decided whether to read `\Per` or `\PerLong`. But it writes, e.g., "N. Per.Long" instead of choosing `\PerLong` = "Niccolò Perotti".

Can this be done somehow, or is there any other, smarter solution, that does not need me to go through my entire thesis changing all arguments in all quotations, but make it possible to control from the preample? And that lets my citations in footnotes stay the same, original form?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: At the risk of emulating the MS Word PaperClip, I'd say "It looks like you're writing a bibliography. Do you need help?" Although it's a bit daunting at first sight, I believe BibLaTeX will do what you want, thus saving you the effort of rolling-your-own.

Comment: Next time you need to cite classical works, you may want to take a look at the `classics` package, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a conditional; with a new command you can define in a coherent way commands with "short" and "long" forms. Then `\citeCL` and `\citeCLLong` can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newif\ifCLLong

\newcommand{\citeCL}[3]{\CLLongfalse #1, \emph{#2}, \textbf{#3}}

\newcommand{\citeCLLong}[3]{\CLLongtrue #1, \emph{#2}, \textbf{#3}}

\newcommand{\QuoteCL}[4]{%
\begin{quote}
#4 \par\hspace*{\fill}\footnotesize\citeCLLong{#1}{#2}{#3}
\end{quote}
}

% Abstraction for easing the definition    
\newcommand{\newshortlongcommand}[3]{\newcommand{#1}{\ifCLLong #3\else #2\fi}}

\newshortlongcommand{\Per}{N. Per.}{Niccolò Perotti}
\newshortlongcommand{\PerRud}{Rud. gram.}{Rudimenta grammatices}

\begin{document}

Testo introduttivo\footnote{\citeCL{\Per}{\PerRud}{§ 1119}}

\QuoteCL{\Per}{\PerRud}{§ 1119}{Quis maxime proponendus est quem studeant adolescentes imitari? Marcus Cicero.}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

(I've simplified the definition of `\QuoteCL`, to get away with `spacing` and inessential things.)

In this way you can also input arguments directly without any worry; for instance

```
\QuoteCL{Niccolò Perotti}{Rudimenta Grammatices}{§ 1119}{...}
```

would work the same.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Change your first two arguments to just text strings, and use the `\csname` `\endcsname` construct to accomplish what you desire. (note: I turned off spacing environment, cause I didn't know what package had it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\citeCL}[3]{\csname#1\endcsname, \emph{\csname#2\endcsname}, \textbf{#3}}
% Original command now used for footnotes

\newcommand{\citeCLLong}[3]{\csname#1Long\endcsname,
\emph{\csname#2Long\endcsname}, \textbf{#3}}
% New command to be called by the \quoteCL command.

\newcommand{\Per}{N. Per.}
\newcommand{\PerLong}{Niccolò Perotti}
\newcommand{\PerRud}{Rud. gram.}
\newcommand{\PerRudLong}{Rudimenta grammatices}
% Duplicating the list of names and titles, adding a long version to be called by the \citeCLLong:

\newcommand{\QuoteCL}[4]{
\vspace{5pt}
\begin{quote}\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt%
%\begin{spacing}{1}%
#4 \par\hspace*{\fill}\footnotesize{\citeCLLong{#1}{#2}{#3}}
%\end{spacing}
\end{quote}
\vspace{-20pt}
}
% The command is changed to call the new \citeCLLong

\begin{document}
\QuoteCL{Per}{PerRud}{§ 1119}{Quis maxime proponendus est quem studeant adolescentes imitari? Marcus Cicero.}

\vspace{6em}
\citeCL{Per}{PerRud}{§ 1119}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico The source had not been saved in UTF-8, and so I had to resave the source with different encoding.  THen both LaTeX and pdfLaTeX both worked fine.